# Using C #, how can I set a variable to a random number within a range?

Tags: c#, class, variables, random, properties

I've created a class called Superhero and given it the properties of:
string Name, int Life, int Punch, int Kick, and int Hyper Punch.

Then inside of my program in the main I created a List.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
List<Superhero> listOfHeroes = new List<Superhero>;
Superhero goodGuy = new Superhero();
goodGuy.Name = "Super Man";
goodGuy.Life = 100;
goodGuy.Punch =????
}
```

I want to be able to put in a range of numbers where the "????" are. My theory is that a user would be able to choose a hero from the list and be able to use him for battle. When he chooses the hero to throw a punch (or a kick or whatever) then a random number within a set range is assigned to that property.

So if it was a two player turn based game the property punch, when used, would take away from the other person's life property by the value of Punch. Is this a possibility or am I going about this incorrectly?

pseudo-random is ok.

Btw, I'm in 4th week of boot camp...so yell at me harshly if none of this makes sense so I can learn quicker lol.

Comment: `int value = Random.Next(min, max-1)`

Comment: @Plutonix When I put that code in I get an error message of "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Random.Next(int,int)' " Is this because I'm not creating an instance of Random?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize a Random instance using:

```
 Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now);
```

Then you can use:

```
int value = rand.Next(min, max-1)
```

If you don't have a global initialization of Random instance, you will have always the same number using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   var t = (new Random()).Next(0, 100);
   Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Will return then time the same value